# loop executes first but its task response late in node js

Tags: node.js, express

Hi what i m trying to do is i have contacts Array and i want to iterate through this and find the contact email in database. For now these emails doesn't exists in database so every time we will get null from result. So on result null i want to add this user details in 'conlist Array' and add user email in 'conlist2 Array' and after this loop rest of my code depends on these Array 'conlist and conslist2'

this is my code below:

```
let conlist2=[];
let conlist=[];

var Contacts=[
    {"FirstName":"Ramesh","LastName":"sharma","Email":"gh6@xyz.com","Phone":"(465) 413-4564"},{"FirstName":"Rajesh","LastName":"sharma","Email":"ankit@xyz.com","Phone":"(465) 413-4564"}
];

          Contacts.forEach(function(element,cb) {

                console.log("loop starts");
                if (element.Email == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    existContact=null;
                    contactModel=null;                                                          

                                    let collection = db.collection("users");                                             
                                    collection.findOne({email:element.Email},function(err,data){

                                if(err){                                                                          
                                    res.json(err);
                                }                                                                     
                                existContact=data;                                                                                                                                    
                                if(existContact==null){
                                    console.log("contact not found");
                                    conlist.push(element);  
                                    console.log(conlist);                                                                       
                                }                                                                       
                                conlist2.push(element.Email);
                                console.log(conlist2);   

                                    cb();
                            });           
                            console.log("loop ends");      
            },function(err){
                    if(err){throw err;}

                    console.log("completed");

                    }); 

                    if(conlist2.length>0)
                    {
                        console.log("hurrey succeed");
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            console.log("u came early");
                        }
```

This is the output i m getting:

```
loop starts <br>
loop ends <br>
loop starts <br>
loop ends <br>
u came early <br>
contact not found <br>
[ { FirstName: 'Ramesh',
    LastName: 'sharma',
    Email: 'gh6@xyz.com',
    Phone: '(465) 413-4564' } ]
[ 'gh6@xyz.com' ] <br>
contact not found <br>
[ { FirstName: 'Ramesh',
    LastName: 'sharma',
    Email: 'gh6@xyz.com',
    Phone: '(465) 413-4564' },
  { FirstName: 'Rajesh',
    LastName: 'sharma',
    Email: 'ankit@xyz.com',
    Phone: '(465) 413-4564' } ]
[ 'gh6@xyz.com', 'ankit@xyz.com' ] <br>
completed <br>
```

/*  --------------------------------------------------  */

but i want output like below:

```
loop starts <br>
contact not found <br>
[ { FirstName: 'Ramesh',
    LastName: 'sharma',
    Email: 'gh6@xyz.com',
    Phone: '(465) 413-4564' } ]
[ 'gh6@xyz.com' ] <br>
loop ends <br>
loop starts <br>
contact not found <br>
[ { FirstName: 'Ramesh',
    LastName: 'sharma',
    Email: 'gh6@xyz.com',
    Phone: '(465) 413-4564' },
  { FirstName: 'Rajesh',
    LastName: 'sharma',
    Email: 'ankit@xyz.com',
    Phone: '(465) 413-4564' } ]
[ 'gh6@xyz.com', 'ankit@xyz.com' ] <br>
loop ends <br>
completed <br>
hurrey succeed <br>
```

Your help would be appreciated
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

nodejs is async in nature when you hit a DB call nw request the process doesnt wait for response and executes further line so make the  functiona synchronized by using async/await or use async library [async_lib](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

for async await method look here [Async/await](https://github.com/vipulpandeykv/NODEJS-starter-app/blob/74bf59378162c741af198ce5ad766c349a06ad56/app/controller/asyncController.js)

Answer (score 0):

Use the async/await or async package. async/await is more preferable.